# TFS: Failed to create Mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I was trying to create a tfs repository for a team project I want to work on.

```
ERROR: 
the mapping for $/progetto/progetto conflicts with one of its parent's mappings.
```

I've created a free tfs server here : `https://progetto.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/progetto/`

I've opened VS2012 and created a new Project, I flagged `"Add to source control"`

I've choosed TFVC, and now I see a my TFS Details `"Progetto -> Build Process Templates"`

Field "type a name for the solution folder" is set to "progetto"

Field "Solution and project file will be added to" is set to  `"$/progetto/progetto"` if I go on, will be show the ERROR!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What are the Workspace Mappings you have setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy, if you map each project to a different local directory, to get confused with how the server mappings and client mappings sync.  To get around this, I always map the base server directory to a single client directory and let TFS match them up; for example:

```
c:\Dev\WS1 <--> $/
```

When you do a get latest for your TFS repository, TFS will simply create any necessary directories; for example:

```
c:\Dev\WS1\Progetto\
```

This should avoid any conflicts.

Comment: First time with TFS :D, I miss to map folders in SOURCE CONTROL EXPLORER

Answer (score 1):

I received this error message via tf.exe - after extensive cloaking, and then deleting all my other workspaces, I realised that the local directory in my `tf workfold /map` command was actually the directory ABOVE the root of my new (local) workspace.

doh!

The cause of this issue is the fact I always change the current directory to that of the workspace I am about to create (as new workspaces are immediately mapped to the current directory, which can cause conflicts when creating multiple workspaces with the same account).  When I then tried to map the parent local directory to a server subdirectory, it failed as the immediate child was mapped to the server root.